# JavaScript problem, it returns unexpected value

Tags: javascript, undefined

The objective of the program is to return the value that exists in one position of an array or another. The problem is that it returns `undefined`.

```
var ONE = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"];

var TWO = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"];

// ONCLICK 
function main() {
  var p = prompt("Choose the ONE variable array or the TWO variable array");
  var l = parseInt(prompt("Choose de position of the value of that array"));        
  console.log(second(l));
  second(p,l);                                          
}

function second(p,l) {
    if (p == "ONE")
        i = 0;
        while (i < 11){
            if (ONE[i] == l){
                return l;
            }
            i++;
        }

    if (p == "TWO")
        i = 0;
        while (i < 11){
            if (TWO[i] == l){
                return l;
            }
            i++;
        }

}
```

Comment: you're only passing one argument into `second()` the first time you call it. So `p` will be defined but `l` won't be.

Comment: well `second` is called but you do nothing with the returned value..... and your console does not match the line under it,.....

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if the position is an index of an array. If it's i'd be something like that

```
var ONE = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"];
var TWO = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"];

function second(p,l) {
    if (p === "ONE") {
        return ONE[l];
    }

    if (p === "TWO") {
        return TWO[l];
    }
}

second("ONE", 0); // output "a1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more elegant solution?

```js
const arrays = {
  ONE : ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"],
  TWO : ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"]
}

// ONCLICK 
function main() {
  var p = prompt("Choose the ONE variable array or the TWO variable array");
  var l = parseInt(prompt("Choose de position of the value of that array"));
  console.log(second(p,l));
  second(p, l);
}

const second = (p, l) => arrays[p][l];

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(second(l));
```

With this code you are calling the function with the first parameter so "p" and no "l" ("l" is undefinded) so when it evaluates its result it's going to return undefinded.